# Split Column of list Panda

Tags: python, pandas, mongodb, dataframe, split

I have a Pandas DataFrame with this column:
This is an extraction from a database in Mongo but I don't know how to handle a column containing both [] and {}:

[image: Problem]

How can split this column into two columns?

Desired result:

[image: Desired result]

Thanks for your help !

Comment: It would be better for reproducibility to avoid images and to provide your data as text. (ideally the output of `df.to_dict('list')`).

Answer (score 1):

You can create a list of dictionaries (instead of a list of lists with dictionaries), then a dataframe and join this to the original df.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {"coeff":[[{"value": 0.0641, "year":2000}],
                 [{"value": 0.0641, "year":2000}],
                 [{"value": 0.0641, "year":2000}],
                 [{"value": 0.0652, "year":2005}]]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
#                                coeff
# 0  [{'value': 0.0641, 'year': 2000}]
# 1  [{'value': 0.0641, 'year': 2000}]
# 2  [{'value': 0.0641, 'year': 2000}]
# 3  [{'value': 0.0652, 'year': 2005}]

df = df.join(pd.DataFrame([x[0] for x in df.coeff]))
#                                coeff   value  year
# 0  [{'value': 0.0641, 'year': 2000}]  0.0641  2000
# 1  [{'value': 0.0641, 'year': 2000}]  0.0641  2000
# 2  [{'value': 0.0641, 'year': 2000}]  0.0641  2000
# 3  [{'value': 0.0652, 'year': 2005}]  0.0652  2005
```

Answer (score 1):

pandas has a function to construct DF from dictionaries

import pandas as pd

```
my_data = {"coeff":[[{"value": 0.0641, "year":2000}],
                 [{"value": 0.0641, "year":2000}],
                 [{"value": 0.0641, "year":2000}],
                 [{"value": 0.0652, "year":2005}]]
           }

df = pd.DataFrame(my_data)

df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_records(d[0] for d in df['coeff'])

print(df2)
```

gives:

```
    value  year
0  0.0641  2000
1  0.0641  2000
2  0.0641  2000
3  0.0652  2005
```

Answer (score 0):

Combine [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) and [`json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html):

```py
out = pd.json_normalize(df['coeff'].explode())
```

Or, if you have only one dictionary per list:

```py
out = pd.json_normalize(df['coeff'].str[0])
```

Or usig [`from_records`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html):

```py
out = pd.DataFrame.from_records(df['coeff'].str[0])
```

Output:

```
    value  year
0  0.0641  2000
1  0.0641  2000
2  0.0641  2000
3  0.0652  2005
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a df out of your base data:

```
data = {"coeff":[[{"value": 0.0641, "year":2000}],
             [{"value": 0.0641, "year":2000}],
             [{"value": 0.0641, "year":2000}],
             [{"value": 0.0652, "year":2005}]]}
```

[image]

Each element in the df is a dictionary within a list. Isolate the dictionary within the list using the apply method and a lambda function to access the first element in the list (the dictionary).

Use .values() to retrieve the dictionary values (year and value) which will exist as an object with dtype dict_values.

The dytpe of dict_values is pretty limiting so wrap it in a list function to convert to a list so you can use slicing and inxdexing:

```
df2 = df.coeff.apply(lambda x: list(x[0].values()))
```

[image]

Use the apply method with a lambda function and index positions to retrieve the years and values respectively, assign these to their respective column names within a dictionary and pass this as an argument into the pd.DataFrame class to create a new dataframe:

```
pd.DataFrame(data = {'year': df2.apply(lambda y: y[1]),
                 'value':df2.apply(lambda y: y[0])})
```

[image]